# Is this loop invariant correct?

Tags: algorithm, loop-invariant

**The pseudocode for linear search loop:**

```
for j = 1 to A.length 
   if(A[j] = v) 
      return j;
return NIL
```

**Loop invariant I've written:**

At the start of each iteration of the for loop, *j* is the next index after where *A[j-1]* doesn't equal *v*.

**Initialization:**

When *j* equals *1* and before checking whether it is lesser than *A.length*, the previous index is *0*. Then *A[0]* doesn't equal to *v*, because in this context *A[0]* doesn't even exist.

**Maintenance:**

If *A[j]* equals *v* then loop terminates. Which means we don't have next iteration. But if it doesn't equal to *v* then next iteration of the loop executes while preserving the loop invariant.

**Termination:**

The conditions causing the for loop to terminate are that *j* is bigger than *A.length* or *v* equals *A[j]*. Because each loop iteration increases *j* by *1*, we have checked every elements of *A* against *v* until *j* is bigger than *A.length*. Hence the algorithm is correct. If *v* equals *A[j]* then it means the we have found the element we've been searching. Thus the algorithm is correct.

Are these correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too bad, but you could make some improvements.

Loop invariant:  The "next after where..." language is clumsy, and you don't use it in the proof that the algorithm is correct, so there's no reason to maintain it.  Something like this would be better: "At the start of each iteration, there does not exist any i < j such that A[i] == v".

The maintenance: The loop continues if A[j] != v.  Since there does not exist any i < j such that A[i] == v, and A[j]!=v, then there also does not exist any i <= j such that A[i] == v, and the loop invariant holds for the next greater value of j.

Then you can use it in the termination condition:  The loop terminates early if it finds v in the array and returns its index.  Otherwise, the loop invariant holds for j == length+1, and it is known that there does not exist any i <= length such that A[i]==v, i.e, that v does not occur in the array.